# javacc: fail to compile the grammar file(.jj)

Tags: java, javacc

I am new to javaCC,and I am using Windows and download version 5.0 and unzip it.I have installed jdk before and I set path properly.but when I want to compile the Simple1.jj, the warning message given like this:

> Warning: ParseException.java: File is obsolete.  Please rename or delete this file so that a new one can be generated for you.

and it does not output any .java file. What to do?

Comment: Did you try deleting ParseException.java before running JavaCC again?  In fact you might as well delete all generated files and then run JavaCC again.

Answer (score 0):

Is the path you want to save to the same as the directory your IDE wants to save to?

Comment: thank you for trying to help me, I am using the command line to compile the file